# Called a .LESS depending on the condition with react

Tags: reactjs, less

My site is on React.JS with compiling the less-loader

I try to make sure when I call my basic `styles.less` file to condition `variables.less` inside because I will use several themes.

I wouldn't have the theme of the information as long as the person is not logged.

The shots I need to have the base file with `styles.less` conditioned `variables.less` import.

I do not really mind to do it.

I can obviously create a .LESS file and add it to load when I have the information like this:

```
import 'common/styles/less/brand/orange.less';
```

But it forces me to rewrite all styles for each item that requires a color change, background etc .. like this :

```
@primaryColor      : #FF6600;
//RESET BLUE COLOR BTN, HOVER, BORDER
a{
  color:@primaryColor;
  &:hover{
    color:darken(@primaryColor,5%);
  }
}
```

There would be there a solution like this  ? 
On reactApp.jsx :

```
import styles={default} 'common/styles/less/styles.less';
```

On `styles.less` :

```
if(styles == 'default'){
  @import "./variables.less";
  elseif (styles == 'oranges'){
    @import "./variables-oranges.less";
  }
}
```

Any suggestions would avoid to rewrite all the CSS is only variable would be welcome, I dry completely on a way to optimize it.

Best regards !

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have a slight misunderstanding of less here. Less is not meant to generate different CSS files based on user input. You'd rather generate all combinations up-front and deliver the CSS files based on conditions. You can either generate full CSS files including the theme, or you can have one generic CSS file and additional CSS files for the themes.

One possible setup could look like this:

- common.less: your generic theme that depends on variables
- orangevars.less: variable definitions for the orange theme
- bluevars.less: variable definitions for the blue theme
- orange.less: this contains only an import to the orange vars and the common theme
- blue.less: this contains only an import to the blue vars and the common theme

After compiling you'd have:

- orange.css
- blue.css

For a non-themed CSS file you could add a defaultvars.less that contains neutral colors etc.

---

Another approach:

- base.less: basic (neutral) theming
- blue.less: blue theme that adds on top of base
- orange.less: orange theme that adds on top of base

It would generate:

- base.css
- blue.css
- orange.css

There's no variables whatsoever here, only plain old CSS cascading. The good point about this is that you can deliver the base.css even before your JS kicks in and loads a theme. Also you can customize totally different aspects of the theme in the extending CSS. You are not bound to only defining variables for pre-defined rules - at the cost of double maintenance and possibly duplicated code.

This approach is also preferred if you're using any 3rd party libraries like bootstrap. By extending on the CSS level, you can still update the libs later on without losing your changes.

---

Which you deliver to the client you can decide dynamically (on client or server).

Comment: I agree with this approach, but my concern is that I'm on React.js, I don't call as CSS, I call directly .less. On my styles.less I have my variables styles by default, I can obviously put the blue / red / orange etc .. but how to select one over another.

Comment: Compiling less files in the browser is discouraged. From the project website: "Using less.js in the browser is great for development, but it's not recommended for production"

Comment: I don't compile .CSS file, my less-loader package deals to transform all my .LESS -> .CSS files, though you gave me an idea, I'll create several styles.less having orange. less / blue.less with all dependencies I need there will be to choose